# rails not requiring from mailers directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am getting an error when I try to instantiate my mailer from rails console. It was created in the default mailers folder. I already tried restarting the app + creating another mailer there, but it doesn't seem rails is picking it up. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > TesterMailer
NameError: uninitialized constant TesterMailer
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/guestweb/api.jtestingapp.com/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bundler/gems/rails-dev-boost-1e0cc0e1a3f6/lib/rails_development_boost/loadable_patch.rb:14:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Also, adding 
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/mailers) to application.rb fixes it, but shouldn't rails autoload it already?

Comment: it definitely should. I get that you're running rails 4.0.3 ? It seems to work here. Didn't you just forget to reload your server when you first created the directory ?

Comment: i tried restarting the server several times. It is super strange. It works only when I add to autoload paths; it stops working if I take it out and restart

Comment: Indeed, very weird. Not able to reproduce here :s